# How to get object from Application Component using Dagger 2 in Android?

Tags: android, dagger-2

I am working on a very poor Android project. All of its Singletons classes are following a wrong pattern. So, I am trying to make it better.

This project contains only `app` module (so it is not a multi-module project).

These are what I added:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [AppModule::class])
interface AppComponent {

    @Component.Factory
    interface Factory {
        fun create(@BindsInstance applicationContext: Context): AppComponent
    }

}

@Module
object AppModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    @JvmStatic
    fun provideAppContext(context: Context) = context

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    @JvmStatic
    fun provideAppDataManager(ctx: Context) = AppDataManager.setupInstance(ctx)

}

class SiteFinderApplication : Application() {

    val component: AppComponent by lazy {
        DaggerAppComponent
                .factory()
                .create(this)
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

    }

}
```

So, based on my understanding `AppDataManager` object is being created when the user launches the app. If my assumption is right then my question is how to get `AppDataManager` object from the Application component in my other activities?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the way. For everyone else who has the same problem, the can do something like this.

I changed my AppComponent class this way:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [AppModule::class])
interface AppComponent {

    @Component.Factory
    interface Factory {
        fun create(@BindsInstance applicationContext: Context): AppComponent
    }

    fun getAppDataManager(): AppDataManager
}
```

And from my activity, I am able to get `AppDataManager` like this:

```
appDataManager = (application as SiteFinderApplication).component.getAppDataManager()
```